# inserting multiple records in flex

Tags: actionscript-3, sqlite, apache-flex, mobile

I,m using following code to insert multiple records to Sqlite db but I,m not getting and records inserted.

```
private var planActivities:SQLStatement;
private var planActivitiesSQL:String = 'INSERT INTO DailyActivities (timestamp, activityId, activityDescription, hours, calPerMin, hoursCompleted, exercisePlanId)                              VALUES (:timestamp, :activityId, :activityDescription, :hours, :calPerMin, :hoursCompleted, :exercisePlanId)';

            private function addPlannedActivities(activities:ArrayCollection):void
        {

            var currentDate:Date = new Date();
            var numberLoops:Number = 0;

            trace("\nNumber of Activities to add " + activities.length);

            planActivities = new SQLStatement();
            planActivities.sqlConnection = model.connection;
            planActivities.text = planActivitiesSQL;
            model.connection.begin();

            for(var i:uint=0; i < activities.length; i++)
            {                   

                planActivities.parameters[":timestamp"] = currentDate;
                planActivities.parameters[":activityId"] = activities[i].activityId;
                planActivities.parameters[":activityDescription"] = activities[i].activityName;
                planActivities.parameters[":hours"] = activities[i].hours;
                planActivities.parameters[":calPerMin"] = activities[i].calPerMin;
                planActivities.parameters[":hoursCompleted"] = activities[i].totalCal;
                planActivities.parameters[":exercisePlanId"] = planId;

                planActivities.execute();                   
            }


            model.connection.commit();

            var resultCheck:SQLResult = planActivities.getResult();
            trace("\nNumber of rows affected :  " + resultCheck.rowsAffected);

            navigator.pushView(exerciseMainView, model);
        }
```

I had event listeners for SQL result and error but that kept giving me errors. There are questions answered of such problem being resolved using INSERT and UNION SELECT Sqlite.

I wanted to know how this can be done in Flex and ActionScript.

Comment: You need Transactions, look here:
http://www.slideshare.net/peterelst/introduction-to-sqlite-in-adobe-air-1627545
Whole slides are usefull, but transactions is 14th one.

Comment: Thanks , for the pointer . I tried it with the transaction but it doesn't seem to add anything it doesn't even give any errors. I have updated the above code.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the document class for Flash, you can easily use it in the Flex also, this example works fine and might give you directions in your project:

```
package
{

import flash.data.SQLConnection;
import flash.data.SQLMode;
import flash.data.SQLStatement;
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.filesystem.File;

public class Main extends MovieClip
{
    private var conn:SQLConnection;

    public function Main()
    {
        createDatabase();
        insertMultipleData();
        showResult();
    }

    private function createDatabase():void
    {
        var dbFile:File= File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath("database.db");
        var createStmt:SQLStatement;
        var sql:String ='CREATE TABLE "content" ("id"  INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,"sometext" TEXT NOT NULL,"somenumber"  NUMBER NOT NULL);';

        conn = new SQLConnection();
        conn.open(dbFile, SQLMode.CREATE);

        createStmt = new SQLStatement();
        createStmt.sqlConnection = conn;
        createStmt.text = sql;
        createStmt.execute();
        createStmt = null;
    }

    private function insertMultipleData():void
    {

        var sql:String="INSERT INTO content (sometext , somenumber) VALUES (@sometext, @somenumber);"
        var someData:Array = [{text: "text1", num: 1}, {text: "text2", num: 2}, {text: "text3", num: 3}, {text: "text4", num: 4}]; // just some data to insert in the database

        var saveStmt:SQLStatement = new SQLStatement();         
        saveStmt.sqlConnection = conn;      

        conn.begin();           
        for (var i:int = 0; i < someData.length; i++)
        {
            saveStmt = new SQLStatement();

            saveStmt.sqlConnection = conn;
            saveStmt.text = sql;
            saveStmt.parameters["@sometext"] = someData[i].text;
            saveStmt.parameters["@somenumber"] = someData[i].num;
            saveStmt.execute();

        }
        conn.commit();
        saveStmt.execute();         
        saveStmt = null;
    }

    private function showResult():void
    {
        var sql:String="SELECT * FROM content";

        var selectStmt:SQLStatement = new SQLStatement();
        selectStmt.sqlConnection = conn;

        selectStmt.text = sql;
        selectStmt.execute();

        var serverResult:Object = selectStmt.getResult().data;          
        for (var i:int = 0; i < serverResult.length; i++)
        {
            trace(serverResult[i].sometext, serverResult[i].somenumber)
        }
        selectStmt = null;
    }

}
```

}

Comment: hey @Sant gMirian could you help me .. i have 
GetMyTasksNew1Result.token = ws.GetMyTasksNew1(SignIn1Result2.lastResult[0].UserId);
this function which invoke the webservice and i am getting the result in the data grid 
 dataProvider="{GetMyTasksNew1Result.lastResult}"
and my call responder is 
<s:CallResponder id="GetMyTasksNew1Result"/>

i want to insert the data using for loop .. coz my result is in 
GetMyTasksNew1Result.LastResult[i]
how can i insert the data in my table using for loop 
coz i have dynamic array could you help me plz .. i will post my Question and will Link Here . Thanks!!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23270092/how-to-insert-data-from-dynamic-array-to-sqlite-db-getting-from-webservice-using
here is the link Could you help me ... Thanks